# Extending AdapterView

Tags: android, android-adapterview

i'm trying to make (for learning purposes) my own implementation of a simple AdapterView where items comes from an basic Adapter (ImageAdapter from sdk samples).

Actual code is like this:

```
    public class MyAdapterView extends AdapterView<ImageAdapter> implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
    private ImageAdapter mAdapter;
    public MyAdapterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initThings();
    }
    private void initThings(){
        setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public ImageAdapter getAdapter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mAdapter;
    }
    @Override
    public void setAdapter(ImageAdapter adapter) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mAdapter=adapter;
        requestLayout();
    }
    View obtainView(int position) {
        View child = mAdapter.getView(position, null, this);
        return child;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
     super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        for(int i=0;i<mAdapter.getCount();i++){
            View child = obtainView(i);
            child.layout(10, 70*i, 70, 70);
            addViewInLayout(child, i, null, true);
        }
        this.invalidate();
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.d("MYEXAMPLES","Clicked an item!");
    }
}
```

This isn't a coding masterpiece, it just displays a pseudo-listview with pictures. I know i could've used ListView, GridView, Spinner, etc. but i'm relative new to android and i'm trying to figure out some things on it.

Well, the question here is:
Why is my **onItemClick** not firing?

Using the same ImageAdapter with a GridView, everything works ok, but when i use with above class, i get nothing.
Inside **AdapterView.java** there is code for those click, longclick, etc events... so why can't i just fire them?
Maybe i'm misunderstanding basic things on how AdapterView works? Should I extend other base classes instead? And why?

Hoping to find more experienced guidance on here, thanks in advance.

Comment: have u get solution??

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look into `AdapterView`'s sources, you'll see that the `OnItemClickListener` gets invoked in a method, called `performItemClick`:

```
public boolean performItemClick(View view, int position, long id) {
    if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
        // ...
        mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(this, view, position, id);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, if you search the `AdapterView` source for where this method is used, you'll see that it isn't called anywhere!

Indeed, if you check the source of the `Gallery` for example, you'll see that the `performItemClick` is called within the handling of the `onSingleTapUp` or `onKeyUp` events.

If you want to use that, you have to detect when a user clicks somewhere and call `performItemClick` on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending the AdapterView, why dont you try with the baseAdapter. When you costumize your Adapter, it has oen method given below.

```
getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup group)
```

in above method you can access the layout for each list item of the listview and here you can set the all supported events for each control.

Comment: I knew about putting my own onClick listeners for each view on the adapter, but is it acceptable?  
I also could do that inside my class adding onClickListeners to every child after "addViewInLayout"...
But I thought The adapter should manage only "items" and the view (AdapterView) should manage the position, events, and so on...
Is the same ListView/GridView do... their hierarchy goes from AdapterView->AbsListView->ListView, so i thought i could do something similar but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I am playing around with something similar and i am using onItem***Selected***Listener which may be more what you are looking for.