# how to set Multiple gridview in same layout in android?

Tags: android

I want to set two grid view for same layout. I can also able to set that within same lay out but due to scrollable control its look like a "wrap_content".

but i want to show full grid view in a screen one after another like below fig.[image]

in above fig. grid view show full height of it.
so please help me.

Thank you .

Comment: please any body known about this, if yes then please help me

Comment: Could you add some images..? If you are trying to fit a larger object in screen then scroll bars is the best bet. Another option is re-sizing but makes undesireable effects.

Comment: If you give us a hint of why you need two gridviews then may be we could suggest a better solution.\

Comment: do you mean 2 gridviews under each other?

Comment: Amit, I am not sure what you are wanting to do.  Can you explain further?  You have two sets of data that are displayed as grid views but the user is confused and does not understand that they are separate data sets?  If so, perhaps show one set then let the user swipe to the next set.

Comment: hi friends, I want to show no of images in two parts of grid view format. part one has heading "other" below this images to be display  and part two has heading "private" and below this images should be desplay. But each grid view must show it full height.

Comment: finally i have done my task using table layout. i have manage table view onprogrssUpdate method. thank you everybody for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY THIS :

```
public void createTableRow_you(int no) {


          tr_u = new TableRow(this);
          LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
                  , LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

          tr_u.setLayoutParams(lp);
          tr_u.setWeightSum((float) 1.0);
          tr_u.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
          tr_u.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL );

          ImageView img1= new ImageView(this);
          //img1.setLayoutParams(lp);
          img1.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

         // img1.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

          if (density == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH) {
              img1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(125, 125 ));

          }else {
              img1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

          }

          if (no < photo_icon_u.size()) {
              img1.setImageDrawable(photo_icon_u.get(no));
              img1.setId(Integer.parseInt(photoID_profile.get(no)));
              img1.setClickable(true);
              img1.setOnClickListener(this);
              img1.setTag("profile");

          }else {
              img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
              img1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }


          ImageView img2= new ImageView(this);
          //img2.setLayoutParams(lp);
          img2.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        //  img2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, (float) 0.33));
        //  img2.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
          if (density == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH) {
              img2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(125, 125 ));
          }else {
              img2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));  
          }

          if (no+1 < photo_icon_u.size() ) {
              img2.setImageDrawable(photo_icon_u.get(no+1));
              img2.setId(Integer.parseInt(photoID_profile.get(no+1)));
              img2.setClickable(true);
              img2.setOnClickListener(this);
              img2.setTag("profile");

          }else {
              img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
              img2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }

          ImageView img3= new ImageView(this);
         // img3.setLayoutParams(lp);
          img3.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        //  img3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, (float) 0.34));
          //img3.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

          if (density == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH) {
              img3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(125, 125 ));
          }else {
              img3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));  
          }

          if ( no+2 <  photo_icon_u.size()) {
              img3.setImageDrawable(photo_icon_u.get(no+2));
              img3.setId(Integer.parseInt(photoID_profile.get(no+2)));
              img3.setClickable(true);
              img3.setOnClickListener(this);
              img3.setTag("profile");
          }else {
              img3.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
              img3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }

          tr_u.addView(img1);
          tr_u.addView(img2);
          tr_u.addView(img3);
        //.  tb_photo_u.addView(tr_u);
          tb_photo_u.addView(tr_u, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have a `GridView` in a `ScrollbarView`. So what you want is not possible. You can have the two gridviews to share the screen space equally.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    .... >
    <GridView android:layout_weight="1"
     ....... >
    <GridView android:layout_weight="1"
     ....... >
</LinearLayout>
```

### Update

There is a download asynctask example [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).
In `onProgressUpdate` set the downloaded image to its view.

```
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setImageToView(bitmapImg, progress[0]); // progress[0] is the index or id.
 }
```

### Update 2

You should do it the hard way. Extend the `AdapterView` class and measure and layout the items yourself. [Here is link for start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563897/extending-adapterview). The layout now would  look like

```
<ScrollView ....>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        .... >
        <MyGridView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         ....... >
        <MyGridView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         ....... >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: but i want Gridviews which show whole height of it. I don't want to share the screen. Is it Possible?

Comment: No. you cannot have gridview inside scrollview

Comment: for satisfaction i have use table layout and adding row with images but i want to load it using AsynchTask.you have any idea abut loading table layout using asynchtask .

Comment: do u load the images from web?

Comment: hi userSeven7s please see my updated question. i want to make it like this

Answer (score 2):

You can't put a GridView inside a ScrollView because the scroll view will eat all the Vertical TouchEvents.
I had to work around this problem as well, my solution was to implement an `AdapterView` by myself to emulate the gridView behevior without extending ScrollView.

I did it with `horizontal LinearLayout` inside a `vertical LinearLayout` and dynamic margin between elements.

that way you will have only a root ScrollView that let you scroll down the layout with all the GridView element.

Comment: Hi Marioo i don't get you exactly, you are using this layouts inside grid view or in any other layout. please can you explain little bit more. and thank you

Comment: no, i didn't use any GridView. I just re-implemented its behavior by myself by the combination of multiple LinearLayout without the scroll.
Actually, after doing that i discovered the TableLayout wich has the same behavior i implemented.

TableLayout:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html

Comment: tha fact, in my point of view, is that you can't put a vertical scroll view into an other one with vertical scroll.
A solution could be to use something that has horizontal scroll ( the new ViewPager for instance) to switch between subsets of images.

for the ViewPager you can take a look here:
http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537

sorry about my english. ;)

Comment: Thanks Marioo, actuly i have implemented this concept using table layout. But i thing you may have some new idea, that's why i have tell you to explain bit more. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some other elements with GridView, I recommend using FrameLayout with layout_weight.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

1st
</FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
2nd
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```